# Calculation of the unit group of a finite ring

Tags: ring-theory, gap, finite-rings

Is there an easy/fast way using GAP to calculate the unit group of a finite ring? For example, the `Units` command does not work for some finite rings:
(I'm using the GAP-package QPA)

```
gap> A:=NakayamaAlgebra([5],GF(3));
gap> IsRing(A);
true
gap> Units(A);
Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `GroupByGenerators' on 2 arguments called from
GroupByGenerators( [  ], one ) at /opt/gap4r8/lib/ring.gi:895 called from
<function "unknown">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at line 4 of *stdin*
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue
brk>
```

Comment: This might be a shortcoming of the elements created by `qpa`. What is the value of the variable `one` when you get into the error loop?

Comment: ok, it works when one translates the quiver algebra into a matrix algebra. thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly easy: `Units`:

```
gap> r:=SmallRing(12,5);
<ring with 1 generators>
gap> Units(r);              
<group with 2 generators>
```

It works by running through all ring elements, so if is not necessarily fast if the ring is finite but large.

Comment: of course I tried this, but it seems not to work for any ring. Ill edit it in my question.