# Unit group structure GAP code.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra

I want the structure of the unit group of the group algebra $F_{3^k}D_{30}$ using GAP, where $F_{3^k}$ is any finite field of characteristic $3$ and $D_{30}$ is the dihedral group of order $30.$ I want how to check in GAP as I don't know its codes.

I only know to assign

$F:=GF(3)$;

$D30=\textrm{DihedralGroup}(30)$;

$FD30:=\textrm{GroupAlgebra}(F,D30)$;

Please help me check the unit group $U(FD30)$ structure in GAP. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @ahulpke sir is there way for normalizer unit group ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670105/the-normalized-unit-group-using-gap

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737648/calculation-of-the-unit-group-of-a-finite-ring). `Units` will not get you anywhere. Would Wedderburn decomposition be of any help?

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov I tried it by Units but didn’t not get anything .

Comment: As I expected - your problem is enormously huge for `Units`.